# How form works in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, forms

Can someone tell me how forms work in ReactJS?

When user click on submit button how data display under the form i see from react documentation ,About form less guide me

for example in very simple way how i display data when click the submit button check the example.display the data bottom the form,when input any text then click the submit button then show me input text bellow the form,how i can do this?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
class FormHandling extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={text:''}
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({
            text:e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        // what i can write ther 
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} placeholder="enter name"  />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"   />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default FormHandling
```

Comment: Can you clarify what answer you're looking for? Are you wanting to know how the Data `onSubmit` is passed from a react frontend to a backend? How to store it in LocalStorage? What is the context of your question? Could you try to give a more concrete example of your problem and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: please now check the question again i update it

Comment: okay, so if I understand correctly, you want to have a div under your input which displays the text you type in correct?

Comment: yes,i display the text under the div when click the submit button

Comment: do you tell me how i solve this problem @Bryan ?

Comment: So for what it appears you want to do ... you could template out a div with `this.state.text` inside.. or create a component where you pass down the state of of text as props and render it that way.. but what have you tried so far? I don't understand the purpose of why you're wanting to do this (I can't add a full answer because it's been disabled)

Comment: @Bryan for learning purpose,i  see that how form work in React

Comment: so then, when you have an `onChange` handler you store the changes of the inputs into the `state`... and on the `onSubmit` handler.. you can pass that state to an API / backend to persist the data in the database... it works fairly similar to a normal form in html

Comment: i store data for few time not require backend.problem is how i manage handleSubmit = () => { //this function ?  }

Comment: so the handle submit will be called with the form is submitted correct? So this is where you'll want to put logic for what you want to do with the data. The issue is you haven't stated what you want to do with the data.. if you want to just show the data from the `handleSubmit` in another div.. then you can create a component and pass the state as props into the component.. your `handleSubmit` could trigger another component to mount or allow a flag that will show another component.. essentially your `handleSubmit` will be the method that will trigger your form data to go somewhere.

Comment: how?please update the code.or share me code on naqvishah582@gmail.com

Comment: just posted an answer..so take a look at it

Comment: was the answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

```js
handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  // 1st -> send code to an api
  fetch('some_url', {
    headers: {   
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.text)
   })
  .then(function(res){ console.log(res) })
  .catch(function(res){ console.log(res) });
 }
}
// 2 -> flag

state = {
 text: '',
 flag: false
}
handleSubmit = e => {
 e.preventDefault();
 this.setState({flag: true});
}
...
return(
 <div>
   <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
   {flag && <OtherComp textFromForm={this.state.text} /> } 
   // or something like this. (if flag is true then render comp) 
   // I didn't proof this but this is the idea of what you'd do.
 </div>
)
```